A variant of Knapsack problem
In the standard Knapsack problem, the objective is to maximize $\sum c_i x_i$. I encounter a variant where the objective is to minimize $\sum c_i a^{x_i}$ where $a\in(0,1)$ is a constant. I am looking for an algorithm (possibly DP-based) with pseudo-polynomial time complexity to solve this problem. My question is whether this is feasible.

Is $x_i$ a nonnegative integer variable or a binary variable?

Which ones are variables, which ones are givens, and what are the constraints?

$x_i$ is a nonnegative integer.

$x_i$ are variables. $c_i$ are given constants. Constraints are standard Knapsack constraints: $\sum a_ix_i\le A$ where $a_i$ and $A$ are constants.

You want to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i a^{x_i}$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i \le A$ and $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
Define value function
$$v(k,B) = \min\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k c_i a^{x_i}: \sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i \le B \land x_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+\right\}$$
so that the original problem is to calculate $v(n,A)$.  The usual dynamic programming approach conditions on the value $y$ of $x_k$ to obtain recursion
$$v(k,B) = \min_{y\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor B/a_k \rfloor\}} \left\{c_k a^y + v(k-1,B-a_k y) \right\}.$$

Alternatively, you can linearize the problem by introducing binary decision variables $z_{ij}$ to indicate whether $x_i=j$.  The problem is then to minimize the linear objective function $$\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor B/a_i \rfloor} a^j z_{ij}$$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i &\le A \\
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor B/a_i \rfloor} j z_{ij} &= x_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \\
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor B/a_i \rfloor} z_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$}
\end{align}
Now call an integer linear programming solver.

Thank you very much for your insightful solution.
